# Security track record of unix programs

Tags: security, vulnerabilities

I'm looking for a database with all the noteworthy unix programs with a timeline of vulnerabilities found in that individual product in some *categories* (remote/local, DoS, privilege elevation, data execution), and and average, *how often these things happen in a yearly basis of each individual product*.

Comment: You might like to describe what you're trying to achieve, rather than bring us in halfway through your problem solving train of thought.

Comment: I'm trying to take an objective look at the security of my system. Instead of blurry views of some individuals, I want to base my evaluation on solid facts. If I have a range of possible products (firewalls for example), I want to see 4 numbers next to each product, which poses more risk. - And the same thing between different kinds of software. I want to answer questions like: is my ftp server more secure than my webserver?

Comment: Good luck with *that* little project.  The upside is that you'll have wonderfully secure systems, because you'll never get time to actually set anything up... <grin>

Comment: So... why the -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like Portaudit has the best indexed list this far. It is tagged with one of the two pieces of information I need: you can identify which package (*product*) has the vulnerability.

It has no information about the *severity*, or at least I could not find it this far.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security-portaudit.html

Answer (score 4):

Something like http://cve.mitre.org/ ?

Comment: Thanks. I see this as a vulnerability archive. Is there any way to query this database in some way similar to what I described? (Average vulnerabilities found / year for different types).

Comment: Yep, download the CVE list and go to town.

Comment: Thanks, I've downloaded the CSV verson, the problem is that it is not properly tagged. Text searching is not an option, just because a product's name is present in the description it soes not neccesarily mean that the given product is vulnerable. Also no means to check the severity of each vulnerability.

Comment: @vbence - it is the closest thing industry has. You could write a more appropriate search analysis function; I think a lot of folks would thank you for it :-)